# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Lexmark CS310dn printer has bad driver

Tags: printing, lexmark

All,

When Ubuntu 20.04 LTS came out my network was slightly different and I could have a hard coded and reserved IP address for my Lexmark CS310dn printer. It's on a hardwired network port. I could print to it from both Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Fedora 32 and Fedora 33 just fine.

Now I can no longer have that hard coded port.

Windows 10 with no drivers installed can find the printer and print in full duplex mode just fine.

Nothing on Linux can print to it. It only shows up once in the printer list, rather than twice like every other printer on the network. When you select it as a print target the task just hangs at "gathering printer information."

Printer firmware version: NH63.VY.N6348
Compile info: 28-Oct-16 12:26, mls-bld

I'm going to check for newer firmware, but I doubt anything newer exists.

This appears to be a Linux specific problem.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there was a firmware update.

https://www.lexmark.com/en_us/printer/7611/Lexmark-CS310dn

[image]

Download, unzip to clean directory, then follow the instructions on how to update the firmware via the printer's browser interface.

There will be no love after the printer reboots. Don't despair. You then need to reboot every Linux machine so it loads the correct files after discovering the printer. Life will then be good.